# Restricted criteria in autofilter VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I want to restrict filters for the "Customer" sheet based on username using VBA. In the "Customer" sheet, there're 3 columns: Customer_Group, Products, and Total_revenue.
Below is my script:

```
Sub Filtering()

Dim UserName As String
UserName = Environ("username")

With Worksheets("Customer").Range("A1:X2995")
    If UserName = "FI1123" Then
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", VisibleDropDown:=False
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Shirt", VisibleDropDown:=False
        Worksheets("Customer").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ElseIf UserName = "DK0029" Then
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("1", "2"), VisibleDropDown:=True
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("Shirt", "Sweater", "Dress"), VisibleDropDown:=True
        Worksheets("Customer").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else: Worksheets("Customer").Visible = xlHidden
    
    
    End If
    
End With

End Sub
```

My expected result should look like this:

1. For the username "FI1123":

```
Customer_Group  Products   Total_revenue
  1              Shirt       294
```

2. For the username "DK0029":

```
Customer_Group  Products   Total_revenue
  1              Shirt       294
  1              Sweater     103
  2              Shirt       76
  2              Sweater     332
  2              Dress       258
```

However, with my code, for username "DK0029", there appears also Customer_Group 1 and Products "Dress". Is there a way to change the code so that the output table is the same to the above?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are using the wrong field-indices for DK0029 - they should also refer to `Field:=1` and `Field:=2`

Comment: No, it's the right one. The purpose is to send out the Customer file to some employees. Employee "FI1123" can only view product_group 1 and products "Shirt", employee "DK0029" can view product_group 1 with products ("Shirt", "Sweater"), product_group 2 with products ("Shirt", "Sweater", "Dress")

Comment: But the columns you want to check/filter on are the same for DK0029 and FI1123: hence you have to use for both autofilter - settings the same fields = columns - or you have to change the range you are filtering